# How to trigger a Lambda with a HTML on button-click

Tags: html, aws-lambda

I am new to Cloud Programming, and need to trigger the Lambda function below (function name = dbscan-py) with a button-click in my HTML code but can't figure out how to, nor know how to debug to see if it's getting triggered.

```
import json
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb')

def dump_table(table_name):

results = []
last_evaluated_key = None
while True:
    if last_evaluated_key:
        response = client.scan(
            TableName=table_name,
            ExclusiveStartKey=last_evaluated_key
    )
    else: 
        response = dynamodb.scan(TableName=table_name)
        last_evaluated_key = response.get('LastEvaluatedKey')
        results.extend(response['Items'])
    if not last_evaluated_key:
        break
return results

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    table_rows=dump_table('log')
    # table_rows is an array/list of rows objects [{ },{},{}]
    text=repr(table_rows)
    # text is human readable in python
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': text
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Deploy the code to AWS or any other provider. Expose an API endpoint for the lambda function. AWS Guide [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html). (Optional - Enable [cors](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html) for your APIs.)
2. On your HTML page. Write an onClick handler for your button

   ```
   <button onclick='call_api_end_point()'>Click Me</button>

   <script type='text/javascript'>
      const api_url = '<your-api-end-point-url-for-the-lambda>';
      function call_api_end_point(){
        fetch(api_url)
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then(function(data) {
           <handle your response here>
         })
      }
   </script>
   ```

Further, there are [more ways](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html) to invoke your lambda functions. The answer is written assuming you are looking for an API endpoint for your lambda service.